# How to use pytorch lightning Accuracy with ignore class?

Tags: python, machine-learning, deep-learning, pytorch, pytorch-lightning

I have some training pipeline which uses `CrossEntropyLoss` with an ignore class.

The model outputs `log_probs` of shape `(150, 3)` - meaning 3 possible classes in batches of 150.

The `label_batch` is of shape `150`, and `torch.max(label_batch)` == `tensor(3, device='cuda:0')`, meaning there is an extra class labeled `3`, which is the ignore class.

The loss handles it fine:

```
self._criterion = nn.CrossEntropyLoss(
    reduction='mean',
    ignore_index=3
)
```

But the accuracy metric thinks class `3` is valid and gives very wrong results:

`self.train_acc = pl.metrics.Accuracy()`

wrong result with `self.train_acc.update(log_probs, label_batch)` because of the `3` label should be ignored.

---

How to correctly use `pl.metrics.Accuracy()` with an ignore class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Copying response from the discussion thread in the github forum https://github.com/PyTorchLightning/pytorch-lightning/discussions/6890

---

It is currently not supported in the accuracy metric, but we have an open PR for implementing that exact feature PyTorchLightning/metrics#155

Currently what you can is instead calculate the confusion matrix and then ignore some classes based on that (remember that the true positive/correctly classified are found on the diagonal of the confusion matrix):

```
ignore_index = 3
metric = ConfusionMatrix(num_classes=3)
confmat = metric(preds, target)
confmat = confmat[:2,:2] # remove last column and row corresponding to class 3
acc = confmat.trace() / confmat.sum()
```

Comment: Thanks! This is a nice answer, but makes me wonder why ALL metrics are not `ConfusionMatrix` based? only updates should go to the matrix, then it should have some properties such as `accuracy`, `f1`, `mcc`. Why are they distinct?

Comment: Also What I ended up doing (before reading this) was `ignored_inds = label_batch == self._ignore_class_num` and `acc.update(log_probs[~ignored_inds, :], label_batch[~ignored_inds])`. Does it make sense?